# On clicking Search Button, display result in the next page

Tags: angularjs

I searched for the solution but could not find the exact solution so posted here.
I have a search bar in the header menu. When search content is typed and clicked on search button, the result needs to be display in a new page (eg. result.html). API is used to fetch the searched result.

I have added js pseudo code below which will explain what I intend to do.

Thank you for the suggestion.

**navigation**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-search-box animate" role="navigation">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" >
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="main-nav">
                <li> ... </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="search-bar-search animate">
                        <div class="container" ng-controller="searchCtrl">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="q" ng-model="q" placeholder="Search for...">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="search()">Search</button>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**Search.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.service('searchService', function($http) {
    this.getResult = function(q) {
        // o/p is in JSON format
        return $http.get('http://mydomainname/api/search/'+q);
    }
});
app.controller('searchCtrl', function ($scope, searchService){
    $scope.search = function (){
        var q = $scope.q;

        searchService.getResult(q).then(function (response){
                $scope.result = response.data;
                // redirect to new template (result.html) and display result
                ...
                ...
            });

    };
});
```

Comment: what's exactly the question? can you post the relevant code..

Comment: pass your search query in $stateParams. and access that on redirected page to call api and bind result data

Comment: If I could have get workable code I would be very much thankful.